# ERROR: py35: InterpreterNotFound: python3.5 even though python3.5 is installed

Tags: python, docker, continuous-integration, tox

I'm running my builds on my CI (bamboo) via tox on docker

my `tox.ini` look like this

```
[tox]
envlist = py27,py35
[testenv]
deps=-rrequirements.txt
commands=pytest
```

i'm running the tests like so

`tox --recreate -vv -i $myindexserver`

Testing the setup locally works (inside docker)

> py27: commands succeeded
>   py35: commands succeeded
>   congratulations :)

But while running the same thing on the CI instance failes with

> ___________________________________ summary_________________________________
>
> py27: commands succeeded
>   ERROR:   py35: InterpreterNotFound: python3.5

inside the docker, running `which python3` and `which python3.5` succeeds

Has anyone faced similar issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the docker container versions used by my local and the one used by the CI were different.

I'm keeping the answer here in the hopes that someone else finds this useful and possibly save the many hours of debugging that I had to waste.

do a `docker images` to find the tag that you're using locally, and check it against the version running inside your CI.